# ASP.NET Core MVC: asp-for Tag Null Property Behavior - VS2017 vs VS2022

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nullreferenceexception, model-binding

I created a web app using ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0 in 2019 using Visual Studio 2017. I'm trying to update it now, and nowadays I also have Visual Studio 2022 installed, so I'm trying to use VS2022 to update it. I'm having a very specific issue, though: When a view contains an input with an asp-for helper tag which refers to a property of a model property that's an instantiation of a class I created, and that model property is null, it gives me a NullReferenceException in VS2022, but doesn't in VS2017. As a simplified example, here's the model class for the view:

```
public class Page
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the Category class:

```
public class Category
{
    public byte ID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryDesc { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, here's the view (the input tag causing the error is the line containing the asp-for attribute referencing Category.ID)

```
@model Page
<html>
    <body>
        <form asp-action="Navigate" method="get">
            <input name="newPage" />
            <input asp-for="Category.ID" />
            <button type="submit">Go to Page</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, it could be the case that Category is null. In VS2017, in the resulting html this would simply result in the attribute 'value=""' showing up for that input. In VS2022, though, it's giving a NullReferenceException. Does anyone know why that might be the case? I can't use VS2017 to update this site forever (the fact that it's on Core 2.0 notwithstanding, of course, which is a whole other conversation). I know why it's happening, of course (because Category is null), so I can look into taking the steps to adjust for this new behavior if necessary, but I'd rather not make any unnecessary changes to kind of a complicated application that we've been using successfully for years unless I really have to. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you please include your complete view?  While loading `asp-for="Category.ID"` can share what are you loading? In addition, what did you mean by `ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0 ` doesn't sounds clear. Can confirm that, is that is asp.net core 2.0 or legacy MVC app? If possible please share the reproducible sample.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it's actually a partial view referenced by multiple views to provide navigation abilities. The complete view is a little long, so I went ahead and updated the question to include a little more view code other than just the problematic input tag, hopefully making it "reproducible". This is indeed a Core 2.0 app, not a legacy MVC app

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron `asp-for` and tag helpers like this are only available in ASP.NET Core and not the .NET Framework based versions of ASP.NET meaning that, despite the clumsy use of "ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0" it should be clear that OP means ASP.NET Core 2.0

Comment: Yeah, I can see how that might be confusing, I just called it that because that's almost verbatim the title of the book I bought on it in 2019 ("Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 2") :D

Comment: "partial view referenced by multiple views"  I would check to be sure all those views' controllers contain this model.

Comment: @pcalkins Yep, the controllers for the views referencing this partial view do indeed contain the Page model; the problem is there exist times in which the Category property could be null. In VS2017 this isn't a problem, but in VS2022 it seems to be. I'm hoping it's just a setting or something

Comment: you might just do:  public Category Category { get; set; } = new Category();  and also initialize the ID...  It's always better not to pass a null but rather a sort of "none" value.  It's sort of odd that the ID is a byte, too.... I suppose the helper will convert that to something else for output?